# Paypal - Magento Mobile

Tags: payment, paypal, mobile

We have a mobile app for our Magento store. On the web version, we are using Paypal Standard and Authorize.net as Payment options.

The issue here is how can I integrate Paypal Standard and Authorize.net or any other Magento Mobile compatible Payment gateway, in order to make the checkout process and experience the same as we are having in Web version.

Apart form that, let me know if I am on a wrong direction and how the above could be achieved in Magento.

I am unaware how payment gateways work in native mobile app for Magento store.

If anyone can shed some light or guide would be thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have an app made by magento for you?

Comment: No, we currently are working on native app without Magento Mobile.

Comment: Means you are using a mobile application with run on magento database and reputation to show the listing and make the order as like web version.

Comment: Sorry but your question is missing key details.  Are you referring to the included Mobile App functionality included with Magento, or the one you pay for: http://www.magentocommerce.com/products/mobile

Comment: We do not wish to pay for Magento Mobile. But tend to develop a native app for our website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in building a mobile app, you should consider taking a look to [Meets SDK](http://www.meets.io). It might make the connection from your app to Magento info much easier.

Unfortunately, it does not come with built-in support for Paypal payment gateways, but it is on the roadmap. You should consider proposing that in the project repository in Github.

In order to implement Paypal, the best place to start researching I think would be the Paypal Developer website, especially the section related with PayPal Mobile: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#mobile

Good luck!